# Why can't my couchapp generate new application?

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I installed couchapp using

```
$ env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" sudo pip install couchapp
```

and there were no errors. But then if I want to create an application,

```
$ couchapp generate helloworld
$
```

Nothing happens...no new folder created, and no feedback from the terminal.

Also, when I use

```
$ help couchapp
-bash: help: no help topics match `couchapp'.  Try `help help' or `man -k couchapp' or `info couchapp'.
```

and the same thing happens for "man -k couchapp".

Does that mean my couchapp wasn't properly installed? But what may have happened?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the old couchapp tool is deprecated.

Try [erica](https://github.com/benoitc/erica) or [kanso](http://kan.so/) instead.